# Given an estimator, how do you find the large-sample confidence interval?

Tags: probability

I'm given three possible estimators for the mean of a random sample of size $n$ from a population with unknown distribution, but it is known that the mean is $\mu$ and the variance is $\sigma^2$. I have to construct the 95% confidence interval for each.

I've found the respective means and variances of each estimator, but I'm not sure whether I need to modify the standard error.

For example, say I have an estimator $\hat{\mu}$ which has mean $\mu$ and variance $\dfrac{n\sigma^2}{2n+1}$. Which interval would be correct?

$$\left(\bar{x}-1.96\sqrt{\frac{n\sigma^2}{(2n+1)n}},~\bar{x}+1.96\sqrt{\frac{n\sigma^2}{(2n+1)n}}\right)$$
or
$$\left(\bar{x}-1.96\sqrt{\frac{n\sigma^2}{2n+1}},~\bar{x}+1.96\sqrt{\frac{n\sigma^2}{2n+1}}\right)$$
Basically it comes down to whether I should substitute variance in the usual standard error, $\sqrt{\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}}$, with the estimator's variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\bar{x}-1.96\sqrt{\frac{n\sigma^2}{(2n+1)n}},~\bar{x}+1.96\sqrt{\frac{n\sigma^2}{(2n+1)n}}\right)$$ is correct. If we look at the variance of the difference between $\bar{x}$ and $\mu$:

$$
Var[\bar{x}-\mu]=Var[\bar{x}]=Var \left [ \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}Var[x_i]\right]=\frac{1}{N^2}N~Var[x_i]=\frac{\sigma ^2}{N}
$$